# JavaScript && JQuery : Iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have managed to get so far but for some reason, it does not match the last number and run the `else` command I have in the code.

My current code is:
[JavaScript Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erae4fhf/7/)

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated as I've spent the last 2 hours trying to figure this problem out and only managed to get this far.

The next and Previous works fine, along with the View more/less. Its the 'View next address' that the code seems to skip the else.

This code here is always skipped, my question is does anyone know why or can point me in the direction of fixing this?

```
else {
  $(".activee").eq(idx).addClass("hidden");
  $(".activee").eq(idx).removeClass("activee").prev().addClass("activee");
  alert("Sorry, there is no more addresses to show...");
  num[idx]--;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Why is it skipping my `else` statement @Guns

Comment: `Why is it skipping my else statement`. That's because the `if()` statement returns false. As simple as this.

Comment: if statement returns true you mean. But yes, that's how if's work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Yeah I know that, but why is it false, I've consoled.logged each index and they all are fine, but when it is equal to num[index] it just don't run the else... its like its broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your fiddle to this:

```
var num = []; // <-- changed to array from object
for (i = 0; i < leng; i++) { // <-- while i < leng
  num.push(i);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erae4fhf/8/)

Comment: That didn't even come up as an error in the Console window, never thought to check that! Thank-you so much!

Answer (score -2):

```
 for (i = 0; i == leng; i++) {
    num.push(0);
  }
```

you're pushing the value 0 to the num array

probably meant to do

```
 for (i = 0; i == leng; i++) {
    num.push(howMany[i]);
  }
```

but I just skimmed the code, so am not sure whether the logic is even valid.

Comment: No, 0 is important to have otherwise the statement: `if(howMany[idx] != num[idx]){} else {}` would always return false but thanks

Comment: exactly, wasn't your question "Why is it skipping my else statement?" because that statement will always be true... unless you can guarantee that howMany will at least have a 0 element.

Comment: But I can because `howMany` is an array of numbers, then each time the button next is pressed, `num` is incremented. The reason why it was always `true` is because I created an `Object` rather than array in `num`.